# how to print the type of an expression in Frege

Tags: frege

In the interactive shell and (online) REPL I can enter

```
:type 1
```

to find out the type of the expression "1". Is there any function that I can use from code to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this at this time.

However, the REPL is itself written in Frege, so it certainly is possible.

The "trick" is to construct a complete program, like

```
module Foo where { x = 1 }
```

and run it through the first compiler passes, up to and including the type checking pass. After that, one could query the symbol table for the top level symbol `x` and its type.

Comment: would it be helpful to file a feature request for that capability?

Comment: To be honest, the most helpful would be a pull request that contains an implementation of something like Haskells Typable. I for my part have some plans for the next months, but it is not Typeable. Can't speak for other contributors, of course.